# Why do my Beamer blocks without title still have a background?

Tags: beamer

I am using a simple custom Beamer theme *Neo*, that I once built from scratch. It basically adapts the colours of the standard Beamer theme, so nothing fancy really happens. Blocks with an empty title still have a darker blue background. Why does this happen? I cannot identify the part of my theme that is responsible for this.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{neo}

\begin{document}
\frame{
  \begin{block}{}
    Here is my text...
  \end{block}
}
\end{document}
```

[image: Block]

Comment: This is a "feature" of the rectangular block, does not happen with rounded blocks.

Comment: @samcarter: Is it possible to disable this "feature" for rectangular blocks?

Comment: Not really (the definition uses some different objects to build the block), but it is possible to use rounded blocks with a corner size of 0 :) I once posted an answer about this - I will search for it.

Comment: your beamer theme is not known or public. for example `Frankfurt` gives rounded block without title part if it is empty.

Comment: @Zarko: Correct, I have emphasized in my question that my theme only changes colours.

Comment: @Zarko Frankfurt uses rounded block - try with any of the themes that use rectangular blocks.

Comment: @samcarter, as you say and I repeat them, however "neo" is not known, even if it only changed colors ... anyway, instead of `block` OP can use `beamercolorbox` :  `\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercolor{mybox}{fg=black,bg=cyan!30}
%
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=1ex,wd=\linewidth]{mybox}
Text
\end{beamercolorbox}
\end{frame}
\end{document}`

Comment: @samcarter this seems to be inconsistent features ... to me more seems to be bug or misfeatures. You provide nice answer (+1).

Comment: @Zarko Thanks :) This is only the tip of the ice berg of inconsistency - don't get me started about shadows and margins between rounded and rectangular blocks :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**New Solution**

With version v0.5 of the tcolorbox inner theme, you can switch on/off the empty title at will:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berlin}


\useinnertheme[showtitle=false]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{block}{}
    Here is my text...
  \end{block}

  \begin{block}{test}
    Here is my text...
  \end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Old Solution**

Print the title only if it is not empty:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Berlin}

\usepackage{xstring}

\setbeamertemplate{block begin}
{
  \par\vskip\medskipamount%
  \IfStrEq{\insertblocktitle}{}{}{
      \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep*=.75ex]{block title}
        \usebeamerfont*{block title}\insertblocktitle%
      \end{beamercolorbox}%
  }
  {\parskip0pt\par}%
  \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block title}
  {}
  {\ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block body}{}{\nointerlineskip\vskip-0.5pt}}%
  \usebeamerfont{block body}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep*=.75ex,vmode]{block body}%
    \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block body}{\vskip-.25ex}{\vskip-.75ex}\vbox{}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{block}{}
    Here is my text...
  \end{block}
  
  \begin{block}{test}
    Here is my text...
  \end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Another (partial) solution**

As this problem does not happen for rounded block, the idea is to use them, but change their definition to have corner radii of 0.

In the following code I fixed the top left corner (marked with `%%%% CHANGED` in the code), the other corners still need to be fixed.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercolor{block title}{bg=blue}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{bg=blue!20}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\beamerboxesrounded[2][]{%
  \global\let\beamer@firstlineitemizeunskip=\relax%
  \vbox\bgroup%
  \setkeys{beamerboxes}{upper=block title,lower=block body,width=\textwidth,shadow=false}%
  \setkeys{beamerboxes}{#1}%
  {%
    \usebeamercolor{\bmb@lower}%
    \globalcolorstrue%
    \colorlet{lower.bg}{bg}%
  }%
  {%
    \usebeamercolor{\bmb@upper}%
    \globalcolorstrue%
    \colorlet{upper.bg}{bg}%
  }%
  %
  % Typeset head
  %
  \vskip4bp
  \setbox\bmb@box=\hbox{%
    \begin{minipage}[b]{\bmb@width}%
      \usebeamercolor[fg]{\bmb@upper}%
      #2%
    \end{minipage}}%
  \ifdim\wd\bmb@box=0pt%
    \setbox\bmb@box=\hbox{}%
    \ht\bmb@box=1.5pt%
    \bmb@prevheight=-4.5pt%
  \else%
    \wd\bmb@box=\bmb@width%
    \bmb@temp=\dp\bmb@box%
    \ifdim\bmb@temp<1.5pt%
      \bmb@temp=1.5pt%
    \fi%
    \setbox\bmb@box=\hbox{\raise\bmb@temp\hbox{\box\bmb@box}}%
    \dp\bmb@box=0pt%
    \bmb@prevheight=\ht\bmb@box%
  \fi%
  \bmb@temp=\bmb@width%
  \bmb@dima=\bmb@temp\advance\bmb@dima by2.2bp%
  \bmb@dimb=\bmb@temp\advance\bmb@dimb by4bp%
  \hbox{%
    \begin{pgfpicture}{0bp}{+-\ht\bmb@box}{0bp}{+-\ht\bmb@box}
      \ifdim\wd\bmb@box=0pt%
        \color{lower.bg}%
      \else%
        \color{upper.bg}%
      \fi%
      \pgfpathqmoveto{-4.2bp}{3bp}
      \pgfpathqcurveto{-2.2bp}{3bp}{-2.2bp}{3bp}{-2.2bp}{3bp} %%%% CHANGED
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\bmb@temp}{3bp}}
      \pgfpathcurveto%
      {\pgfpoint{\bmb@dima}{3bp}}%
      {\pgfpoint{\bmb@dimb}{1.2bp}}%
      {\pgfpoint{\bmb@dimb}{-1bp}}%
      \bmb@dima=-\ht\bmb@box%
      \advance\bmb@dima by-2pt%
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\bmb@dimb}{\bmb@dima}}
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-4bp}{\bmb@dima}}
      \pgfusepath{fill}
    \end{pgfpicture}%
    \copy\bmb@box%
  }%
  \nointerlineskip%
  \vskip-1pt%
  \ifdim\wd\bmb@box=0pt%
  \else%
  \hbox{%
    \begin{pgfpicture}{0pt}{0pt}{\bmb@width}{60pt}
      \bmb@dima=\bmb@width%
      \advance\bmb@dima by8bp%
      \pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpoint{-4bp}{-1bp}}{\pgfpoint{\bmb@dima}{8bp}}
      \pgfusepath{clip}
      {\pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{-4bp}{0bp}}\pgftext[left,base]{\pgfuseshading{bmb@transition}}}%
    \end{pgfpicture}%
  }%
  \nointerlineskip%
  \vskip-0.5pt%
  \fi%
  \ifbmb@shadow%
    \setbox\bmb@boxshadow=\hbox{\pgfuseshading{bmb@shadow}}%
    \setbox\bmb@boxshadowball=\hbox{\pgfuseshading{bmb@shadowball}}%
    \setbox\bmb@boxshadowballlarge=\hbox{\pgfuseshading{bmb@shadowballlarge}}%
  \fi%
  \setbox\bmb@colorbox=\hbox{{\pgfpicturetrue\pgfsetcolor{lower.bg}}}%
  \setbox\bmb@box=\hbox\bgroup\begin{minipage}[b]{\bmb@width}%
    \vskip2pt%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{\bmb@lower}%
    \colorlet{beamerstructure}{upper.bg}%
    \colorlet{structure}{upper.bg}%
    %\color{.}%
  }
  
\def\endbeamerboxesrounded{%
  \end{minipage}\egroup%
  \wd\bmb@box=\bmb@width%
  \bmb@temp=\dp\bmb@box%
  \advance\bmb@temp by.5pt%
  \setbox\bmb@box=\hbox{\raise\bmb@temp\hbox{\box\bmb@box}}%
  \dp\bmb@box=0pt%
  \bmb@temp=\wd\bmb@box%
  \bmb@dima=\bmb@temp\advance\bmb@dima by2.2bp%
  \bmb@dimb=\bmb@temp\advance\bmb@dimb by4bp%
  \hbox{%
    \begin{pgfpicture}{0bp}{0bp}{0bp}{0bp}
      \ifbmb@shadow%
      {\pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{4bp}{-3bp}}\pgftext{\copy\bmb@boxshadowball}}
      \begin{pgfscope}
        {%
        \advance\bmb@temp by-1bp%
        \pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpoint{\bmb@temp}{-7bp}}{\pgfpoint{9bp}{9bp}}%
        \pgfusepath{clip}
        }%
        {\pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{\bmb@temp}{1bp}}\pgftext{\box\bmb@boxshadowballlarge}}
      \end{pgfscope}
      \begin{pgfscope}
        \advance\bmb@temp by-4bp%
        \pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpoint{4bp}{-7bp}}{\pgfpoint{\bmb@temp}{5bp}}
        \pgfusepath{clip}
        {\pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{4bp}{-7bp}}\pgftext[left,base]{\copy\bmb@boxshadow}}%
      \end{pgfscope}
      \begin{pgfscope}
        \advance\bmb@temp by 4bp%
        \bmb@dima=\ht\bmb@box%
        \advance\bmb@dima by\bmb@prevheight%
        \advance\bmb@dima by 4bp%
        \pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpoint{\bmb@temp}{1bp}}{\pgfpoint{4bp}{\bmb@dima}}
        \pgfusepath{clip}
        \advance\bmb@dima by-4bp%
        {\pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{\bmb@temp}{\bmb@dima}}\pgftext{\box\bmb@boxshadowball}}
        \advance\bmb@dima by-1bp%
        \pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpoint{\bmb@temp}{1bp}}{\pgfpoint{4bp}{\bmb@dima}}
        \pgfusepath{clip}
        \advance\bmb@temp by4bp%
        {\pgftransformshift{\pgfpoint{\bmb@temp}{-3bp}}%
          \pgftransformrotate{90}%
          \pgftext[left,base]{\box\bmb@boxshadow}}%
      \end{pgfscope}
      \fi%
      \unhbox\bmb@colorbox%
      \pgfpathqmoveto{-4bp}{1bp}
      \pgfpathqcurveto{-4bp}{-1.2bp}{-2.2bp}{-3bp}{0bp}{-3bp}
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\the\bmb@temp}{-3bp}}
      \pgfpathcurveto%
      {\pgfpoint{\the\bmb@dima}{-3bp}}%
      {\pgfpoint{\the\bmb@dimb}{-1.2bp}}%
      {\pgfpoint{\the\bmb@dimb}{1bp}}%
      {
      \bmb@dima=\ht\bmb@box%
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\bmb@dimb}{\bmb@dima}}
      \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-4bp}{\bmb@dima}}
      \pgfusepath{fill}
      }
      \ifbmb@shadow%
      {
        \color{black!50!bg}
        \pgfsetlinewidth{0pt}
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\bmb@dimb}{-.5bp}}
        \bmb@dima=\ht\bmb@box%
        \advance\bmb@dima by\bmb@prevheight%
        \advance\bmb@dima by 1bp%
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\bmb@dimb}{\bmb@dima}}
        \pgfusepath{stroke}
        \bmb@temp=\bmb@dima
        \advance\bmb@dima by 1bp%
        \color{black!31!bg}
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\bmb@dimb}{\bmb@temp}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\bmb@dimb}{\bmb@dima}}
        \pgfusepath{stroke}
        \advance\bmb@dima by 1bp%
        \advance\bmb@temp by 1bp%
        \color{black!19!bg}
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\bmb@dimb}{\bmb@temp}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\bmb@dimb}{\bmb@dima}}
        \pgfusepath{stroke}
        \advance\bmb@dima by 1bp%
        \advance\bmb@temp by 1bp%
        \color{black!6!bg}
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\bmb@dimb}{\bmb@temp}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\bmb@dimb}{\bmb@dima}}
        \pgfusepath{stroke}
        \advance\bmb@dima by 1.5bp%
        \advance\bmb@temp by 1bp%
        \color{bg}
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{\bmb@dimb}{\bmb@temp}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\bmb@dimb}{\bmb@dima}}
        \pgfusepath{stroke}
      }
      \fi
    \end{pgfpicture}%
    \box\bmb@box%
  }%
  \ifbmb@shadow%
    \vskip4bp minus 2bp%
  \else%
    \vskip2bp%
  \fi%
  \egroup% of \vbox\bgroup
}  
\makeatother

\setbeamertemplate{block begin}
{%
  \par\vskip\medskipamount%
  \begin{beamerboxesrounded}[upper=block title,lower=block body]%
    {\raggedright\usebeamerfont*{block title}\insertblocktitle}%
    \raggedright%
    \usebeamerfont{block body}%
}
\setbeamertemplate{block end}
{\end{beamerboxesrounded}\vskip\smallskipamount}


\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{}
content...
\end{block}
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

[image]