# How to omit the title bar of a block?

Tags: beamer, block

I want to omit the title bar of a block:
So to go from [image]

this to just that [image]

I know there is the `\usepackage{framed, color}` but I do not know how to get the exact same color that is provided in the theme that I`m using

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{framed, color}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{1,0.8,0.3}
%Zitate und todos
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis} %wie weit man ist
\setbeamertemplate{frame numbering}[fraction]
\useoutertheme{metropolis}
\useinnertheme{metropolis}
\usecolortheme{spruce}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=white}

%ShortTitle wird nicht angezeigt
\title[]{title}
%\subtitle{Subtitle Here}
\author{author}
\institute{}
\date{}
\begin{document}
    \metroset{block=fill}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Wdhlg: Das Pumping-Lemma}
    \begin{block}{}
        Sei L regulär. Dann gibt es eine Zahl $n \geq 1$, sodass jedes Wort $w \in L$ mit $|w| \geq n$ zerlegbar ist in Wörter $x,y,z$ mit $w=xyz$, die die folgenden Eigenschaften haben:\\
        $y \neq \epsilon$
        $\hspace{1.5cm}$
        $|xy| \leq n$
        $\hspace{1.5cm}$
        $xy^kz \in L$ für alle $k \in \N$.
    \end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Although about an entirely different beamer theme, the underlaying issue of rectangular blocks keeping the title's background color, altough no block title is given seems to be the same in this question and the answer should also work in your case: [Why do my Beamer blocks without title still have a background?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/377777/134144)

Answer (score 1):

I omitted it by using the shaded-environment and figured out the colour coordinates using paint

Answer (score 1):

This is how did it after much trial and error.

```
\metroset{block=fill}
\setbeamercolor{block title example}{bg=}

\begin{exampleblock}{}
    \vspace*{2em} 
    \begin{quote}
      Content
    \end{quote}
    \vspace*{2.5ex}
\end{exampleblock}
```

Note that, this is the exact example I used in one of my presentations.
The vspace and quote environment were used for padding and centering the content nicely.

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

With the new version v0.5 of the tcolorbox inner theme, you can switch the empty title on/off at will:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{todonotes}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme
\usecolortheme{spruce}

\setbeamercolor{block title}{%
  use=normal text,
  fg=normal text.fg,
  bg=normal text.bg!80!fg
}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{
  use={block title, normal text},
  bg=block title.bg!50!normal text.bg
}

\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=white}

%ShortTitle wird nicht angezeigt
\title[]{title}
%\subtitle{Subtitle Here}
\author{author}
\institute{}
\date{}

\useinnertheme[showtitle=false]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Wdhlg: Das Pumping-Lemma}
    \begin{block}{}
        Sei L regulär. Dann gibt es eine Zahl $n \geq 1$, sodass jedes Wort $w \in L$ mit $|w| \geq n$ zerlegbar ist in Wörter $x,y,z$ mit $w=xyz$, die die folgenden Eigenschaften haben:\\
        $y \neq \epsilon$
        $\hspace{1.5cm}$
        $|xy| \leq n$
        $\hspace{1.5cm}$
        $xy^kz \in L$ für alle $k \in N$.
    \end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]